# What problems lead Stroustrup to say C++ exceptions are "badly implemented in a lot of places"?

Tags: c++, exception, rtti

A short while ago, @BjarneStroustrup said in his [Meeting C++ 2016 Keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvUL0Y2bpyc&) (at 01:44:40, almost at the end, in a reply to a question about RTTI), that

> RTTI is very badly implemented in a lot of places, and that's the same kind of problem as we have with exceptions. etc. etc.

What criticism has been levelled at implementations of exceptions in a "lot of places" that might lead to this strongly-worded conclusion? And What kind of places was Bjarne referring to?

Comment: I think he means to say e.g. dynamic_cast is slow relative to what should be possible if the whole RTTI system was implemented more efficiently than it currently is (which I think he knows is possible, as he's written some papers on how to do this).

Comment: First of all when exception is propagating back through the stack one must match actual exception class with what is expected by "catch" - this is something similar to dynamic_cast in RTTI and so (most likely) uses the same "badly implemented" stuff as RTTI uses for dynamic_cast.

Comment: This an interesting question, and although I have voted to re-open it after you changed the phrasing, I fear it may still be quite controversial on Stack Overflow. It might be a better fit over on [Programmers.SE]—certainly worth investigating a migration if it gets re-opened and then closed again.

Comment: @CodyGray: At the moment, there are 4 reopen votes. If it doesn't get reopened I might try it on SE.SX.

Comment: As all we can do is *speculate* about the thoughts in Bjani's head, this question is *primarilly opinion based*.